# mysql querying age from dob

Tags: mysql, date

My MySQL database has date of birth stored in the format yyyy-mm-dd, how do I query the database - without using php code - to show me results of people born within x years of now, and/or, who are y years of age?

The table is called users, the colum is called dob. I've spent a while viewing the MySQL manual but I can't work out precisely how to form my query.

So far I went for `select * from users where dob...` but I don't think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `INTERVAL` command.

```
SELECT * from users where dob >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR)
```

This returns all users under the age of 18.

Comment: Thanks! I was playing with the interval but couldn't get it to do what I wanted, saved me hours of fruitlessness. Just want to add that I had to remove the S from YEARS to make it YEAR, more for in case someone views this question in the future. Again, many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I couldn't remember it offhand. I'll edit in the fix.